# General solution to $\int_0^\infty\left[1-\tanh{\left(\frac{z+p}{\delta}\right)^{2n}}\right]\text{d} z$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I've already tried to use the Feynman integration technique and some other differentiation under the integral sign methods but cannot seem to crack this problem. Any push in the right direction would be appreciated. Reciting, we're interested in:
$$\int_0^\infty\left[1-\tanh{\left(\frac{z+p}{\delta}\right)^{2n}}\right]\text{d} z$$

with $p\geq 0$, $\delta>0$ and $n \in  \mathbb N$.

Comment: I'd probably start with finding a general formula for $\tanh^{2n}(x)$ and see where that leads. That may simplify your integrand down into something more manageable.

Comment: Are you completely sure this integral even has a closed form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without bounds, your integral can be expressed in terms of the [incomplete beta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) $\operatorname{B}_z(a, b)$, where
$$
\int\left[1-\tanh^{2n}{\left(\frac{z+p}{\delta}\right)}\right]\text{d}z = z - \frac{\delta}{2}\operatorname{B}_{\tanh^2\left(\frac{z+p}{\delta}\right)}\left(n+\frac{1}{2}, 0\right) + C,
$$
but this is quite unhandable for your given bounds. Following [this source](https://books.google.es/books?id=aBgFYxKHUjsC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=integral%20sech%5E(2n)(x)&source=bl&ots=bNhuQWBdPx&sig=ACfU3U0BpwAHmOusE-w06oMXye13KD-2eQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwisq6C23bb1AhWIERQKHWaTCSQQ6AF6BAgmEAM#v=onepage&q=integral%20sech%5E(2n)(x)&f=false) (integral 2.424.3), check that
$$
\int \tanh^{2n}z \mathrm{d}z = z-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\tanh^{2n-2k+1}z}{2n-2k+1}.
$$

You can derive this result taking into account that
$$
\tanh^{2n}z = (1-\operatorname{sech}^2z)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\operatorname{sech}^{2k}z.
$$

Going back to your integral, let $u:= (z+p)/\delta$, so
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int^\infty_0\left[1-\tanh^{2n}{\left(\frac{z+p}{\delta}\right)}\right]\text{d}z &= \int^\infty_0\mathrm{d}z - \delta\int^\infty_{p/\delta}\tanh^{2n}u\mathrm{d}u \\
&= \delta\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1-\tanh^{2n-2k+1}\left(p/\delta\right)}{2n-2k+1}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error, mate!

Comment: Ofcourse, binomial expansion makes perfect sense. Elegant/simple, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

We know the antiderivative
$$I=\int \left(1-\tanh^{2n}(x)\right)\,dx$$
$$I=x-\frac{\tanh ^{2 n+1}(x) \,\,\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{2 n+1}{2};\frac{2 n+3}{2} ;\tanh ^2(x)\right)}{2 n+1}$$

So, for
$$J=\int_0^\infty\left[1-\tanh{\left(\frac{z+p}{\delta}\right)^{2n}}\right]\,dz$$
$$J=\delta  \left(\frac{a_n}{b_n}+\frac{\Bigg[\tanh \left(\frac{p}{\delta }\right)\Bigg]^{2 n+1}
   }{2 n+1}\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{2n+1}{2};\frac{2n+3}{2};\Bigg[\tanh \left(\frac{p}{\delta
   }\right)\Bigg]^2\right)\right)-p$$

The $a_n$ and $b_n$ correspond to sequence $A025550$ and $A025547$ in $OEIS$, the sequence of their first ratios is
$$\left\{1,\frac{4}{3},\frac{23}{15},\frac{176}{105},\frac{563}{315},\frac{6508}{3465},\frac{88069}{45045},\frac{91072}{45045},\frac{1593269}{765765},\frac{31037876}{14549535},\frac{31730711}{14549535},\cdots\right\}$$